# Socket.Close() doesn't terminate Socket.Accept()!

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public static void main()
{
    Socket _SocketTCP = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _SocketTCP.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));
    _SocketTCP.Listen(5);

    while (true)
    {
        Socket socket;

        try
        {
            socket = _SocketTCP.Accept();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("A Client Connected");
    }  
    Console.WriteLine("Server Closed");
}
```

In another thread I call `_SocketTCP.Close();`. However, the while loop never exits and "Server Closed" is never printed after I call the `_SocketTCP.Close();` method.
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Please create executable repro code. Normally, this works... I think.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you're catching `ObjectDisposedException` you need to actually call `Dispose` method on your `_SocketTCP`.

Comment: The `Socket.Close()` method disposes the `Socket` object. The `Socket.Receive()` method gets terminated it throws `ObjectDisposedException` when the `Socket.Close()` method is called. However, this doesn't work with the `Socket.Accept()` method.

Comment: @None yep, you're right, sorry. Could you try to catch `SocketException`, not `ObjectDisposedException`? It should give you a message like `A blocking operation was cancled by blah-blah-blah`? If it's not gonna work for you, please, provide a code where you call `Close()` on your `Socket`, cuz your case is really weird :)